# Regular expression in form of string not working in Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby, string

I have regular expressions stored in a variable -
`s="/\A([^@\s]+)@((?:a-b+\.)+(in|com))\z/"`.

```
"sourabh@a-b.in".match?(/\A([^@\s]+)@((?:a-b+\.)+(in|com))\z/) => returns true
Regexp.new(s) => returns /\/A([^@ ]+)@((?:a-b+.)+(in|com))z\//
"sourabh@a-b.in".match?(Regexp.new(s)) => returns false
```

While storing the regular expression in the database the `\` is removed automatically.
I will get the regex validator in the form of a string. Don't know why it is not working?

Comment: When passing the regex pattern to a DB, save it as a plain string there. Then, when getting it from DB, use `Regexp` constructor.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you please help me to convert this `/\A([^@\s]+)@((?:a-b+\.)+(in|com))\z/` regex to plain string.

Comment: I added a whole answer with examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes (cf [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Single_quotes))

```
> puts "/\A([^@\s]+)@((?:a-b+\.)+(in|com))\z/"
/A([^@ ]+)@((?:a-b+.)+(in|com))z/

> puts '/\A([^@\s]+)@((?:a-b+\.)+(in|com))\z/'
/\A([^@\s]+)@((?:a-b+\.)+(in|com))\z/
```

Then remove the starting and ending '/':

```
> s = '\A([^@\s]+)@((?:a-b+\.)+(in|com))\z'
=> "\\A([^@\\s]+)@((?:a-b+\\.)+(in|com))\\z"

> reg = Regexp.new s
=> /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:a-b+\.)+(in|com))\z/

> "sourabh@a-b.in".match?(Regexp.new(reg))
=> true
```

Comment: ...or `Regexp.new("\\A([^@\\s]+)@((?:a-b+\\.)+(in|com))\\z") #=> /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:a-b+\.)+(in|com))\z/`.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to store a regular expression pattern inside a database, a common approach is to store the pattern / flags as a *string*.

Thus, in case you are going to use a single column to store regex data, you may use [`Regexp#to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-i-to_s):

```rb
regex_string = /.../.to_s
```

If you want to store the pattern ([`source`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-i-source)) and flags ([`options`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-i-options)) as separate strings:

```
regex_pattern = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:a-b+\.)+(in|com))\z/.source
regex_flags = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:a-b+\.)+(in|com))\z/.options
```

Once you read the values from a databse, you can use the [`Regexp.new` constructor](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-c-new) to get the regex object back:

```rb
rx = Regexp.new(regex_string)
# or
rx = Regexp.new(regex_pattern, regex_flags)
```

See [`Regexp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html) Ruby documentation.